# How can I create a custom Django widget that adds jQuery Grid Manager drag and drop editing feature to a Django TextArea

Tags: jquery, django, python-3.x

I want to add a custom drag & drop editor that will enable users to dynamically create content grid layout that is saved unto a Django admin TextField. I have researched here on Stackoverflow and majority of the examples I found used ckeditor, tinymce or any of the other wysiwyg editors. In this use case, I want to use jQuery Grid Manager. See demo of what I am hoping to add to the DjangoTextField pulled from the jQuery Grid Manager site: http://neokoenig.github.io/jQuery-gridmanager/demo/foundation.html.

Comment: Too abstract question. Please describe more

Comment: @seuling , I have updated the question.

Comment: Can you show what you have so far? Describe any issues you can't troubleshoot? Can't help if the problem isn't clear.